# Site icons on stackexchange.com messed up again

Tags: bug, icons

[image]

I was searching for transcripts in a chatroom when I noticed this. The notifications in the FH circle have wrong icons. They're actually SO, MSE and Information Security, but the icon looks like Meta Cross Validated, Cross Validated and SF Meta.

Page refreshed, browser cache cleared, still same.

They look rather OK on any Q&A sites.

[image]

Comment: I think it is *still messed up* (if that is a kind way to express the issue) and it was said a server-side cache should expire on monday to rectify this problem.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xGqUc.jpg causes my browser issues...

Comment: I also see what @RoryAlsop sees.